# How do I get a value from a particular location on screen using Sikuli(Java)?

Tags: java, testing, automation, automated-tests, sikuli

My scenario:

Trying to automate Calculator using Sikuli(Java). I need to get the result (in text) every time an operation is completed.
Example: 1 * 2 = 2. Need to capture '2' from the resulting area/region.
Can some one please help me how can I do it?

The result may be dynamic, so It becomes important for me to read it in run time and then compare it with the input values.

Thank you,
Mike

Comment: I don't know anything about `sikuli` but this is really easy to achieve with `java.awt.Robot`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the resulting area is a text field you can click on it, copy the text to the clipboard and read it from Env.getClipboard():

```
click("text_field.png")
type("a", KEY_CTRL)
type("c", KEY_CTRL)
print Env.getClipboard().strip()
```

Another way is to find left and right borders of the result field, drag the mouse cursor from left border to the right, copy the text via ctrl+c and use Env.getClipboard() to get it.

Hope that helps.